# Magento 2 homepage issue | CSS and Layout differ from any other pages

Tags: css, magento, magento2.1

I have a really weird problem with my `magento 2.1.8` website. Suddenly, the homepage started to look a look different from any other pages on my site.

The home page:

[image]

Any other page on my site:

[image]

As you can see the homepage loads a completely a different class to other pages on my website... What could cause this problem? Anyone came across this before?

UPDATE:

When I add session id to the homepage url /?SID=5d1ia2d0j92bn95qbc9g5jc7l3 it displays the site correctly...

UPDATE 2:

When I go to the browser and go to my website by typing domain.co.uk it redirects me and assigns a session ID to it. The website is then being displayed properly. However, when I type in **www**.domain.co.uk, it doesn't assign the session ID and the homepage look totally different.

UPDATE 3:

When I navigate to my website using http://domain.co.uk it redirects me to https://www.domain.co.uk/?SID=1m9tt10hmga4slep7sac8ur8v2 and everything is working fine. When I add http**s** or add **www** to the URL it redirects me to https://www.domain.co.uk/ without a session ID where CSS is completely different to what it should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After dreadful investigation...

I have a server side scanner running every weekend. The scanner was sending alot of post requests and managed to send a request to change a theme in "panel tool".

It didn't have any effect on the website until Varnish cached this request and started displaying this cached version to customers.

After purging Varnish cache and disallowing the server side scanner of accessing "panel tool" the site went back to normal.